# Consultando situação de múltiplos CNPJs na Receita Federal

Tags: independente-de-linguagem

Me passaram uma missão ingrata de consultar na base da Receita Federal a situação de diversos CNPJ's (mais de 1000).

Existe alguma maneira programática de fazer isso, e de preferência que não tenha custos?

Comment: +1, Pelo que conheço apenas empresas credenciadas podem ter um serviço de webservice para realizar isto, é elas são pagas, seria de grande ajuda uma API gratuita para realizar estas consultas.

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues Tem empresas que fazem em lote também. A meu ver, a Secretaria da Fazenda podia deixar essa base mais acessível.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Uma possibilidade para quem tem um certificado digital (e-CNPJ, NFe etc) é utilizar o sistema disponibilizado pela SEFAZ como parte da estrutura de NFe:

```
CadConsultaCadastro2
```

Vou tomar como exemplo o endereço do *webservice* do Estado de São Paulo:

```
https://nfe.fazenda.sp.gov.br/ws/cadconsultacadastro2.asmx
```

Como a documentação da SEFAZ é um tanto complexa de se entender, vou simplificar e mostrar a requisição na íntegra, pois fica mais fácil de cada um adaptar para o seu ambiente.

Segue a requisição completa em SOAP 1.2, que deve ser feita com HTTPS usando o certificado digital:

```
POST /ws/cadconsultacadastro2.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: nfe.fazenda.sp.gov.br
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8;
 action="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/CadConsultaCadastro2/consultaCadastro2
Content-Length: 0000

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                 xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Header>
    <nfeCabecMsg xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/CadConsultaCadastro2">
      <cUF>35</cUF>
      <versaoDados>2.00</versaoDados>
    </nfeCabecMsg>
  </soap12:Header>
  <soap12:Body>
    <nfeDadosMsg xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/CadConsultaCadastro2">
      <ConsCad xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe" versao="2.00">
        <infCons>
          <xServ>CONS-CAD</xServ>
          <UF>SP</UF>
          <CNPJ>00000000000000</CNPJ>
        </infCons>
      </ConsCad>
   </nfeDadosMsg>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

### Importante:

- As quebras de linha e espaços entre as tags são apenas para facilitar a leitura. A SEFAZ escolheu XML como formato de embalar os dados, mas ...por economia de espaço... nos faz trabalhar como se fosse TXT. Então mande tudo enfileirado em uma linha só (exceto os cabeçalhos do POST e a linha em branco que o separa do BODY).
- O `Content-length:` deve ser calculado conforme o tamanho do corpo do POST, é a quantidade de *bytes* de `<?xml` em diante.
- O CNPJ deve ser preenchido com 14 dígitos, sem pontos nem traços
- O campo UF é a sigla, mas o campo cUF é código numérico do estado.
- Cada estado tem seu endereço próprio, e a requisição deve ser feita para a SeFaz correspondente.
- Me parece que o Amazonas não disponibiliza este *service*.
- Segue o endereço dos *webservices* de cada região:
  http://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/portal/WebServices.aspx
- Imagino que haja um limite de consultas x tempo, mas não achei estas medidas na documentação toda espalhada da SeFaz. Sugiro fazer a consulta em pequenos lotes e com intervalos razoáveis. Como mencionado pelo colega [@Denis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/53279), tem algumas recomendações gerais em [um PDF da SEFAZ](https://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/portal/exibirArquivo.aspx?conteudo=IjF66WihatE=).
- Com o tempo esta resposta vai ficar desatualizada. Quem tiver problemas para implementar, deixe um comment que à medida do possível podemos mantê-la atualizada.

Agradecimentos ao @jbueno e ao @Cigano, que ajudaram a desenvolver e fazer testes antes da publicação da resposta.

Comment: @Baco, encontrei [essas](https://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/portal/exibirArquivo.aspx?conteudo=IjF66WihatE=) informações sobre tempo limite

Comment: @DenisRudneideSouza seu avatar me lembrou [desse clipe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gzfaJRDfveo)

Comment: @DenisRudneideSouza para adiantar parte da curiosidade, é um clipe da Goldfrapp, segue um frame de referência https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/fa/d0/e9/fad0e9444b2d63745a46a7352de76a4a.jpg